# Is it possible to call stored Procedure from .net application passing list of Array of string or integer as parameter

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I know this is possible from Database to create a Type and send it to Stored procedure as a parameter .

**But it seems it does not work with .net application, be it ADO.net or Nhibernate.**

**Oracle Version**

10g.

**ODP.net**

11.2

**Assembly Version**  :2.112.2.0

**Product Version** :  2.112.2.0

**DLL**:  Oracle.DataAccess.dll

**Type Created IN ORACLE**

create or replace TYPE NUMBER_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER  ;

**Stored Procedure**
                                                                                            create or replace PROCEDURE odp_varray_sample_proc_test(param IN NUMBER_ARRAY)
IS
BEGIN 
insert into employee (emp_id, emp_name, emp_password, is_captain, no_of_mom) 
values (45455,'Adam','123545','Y',0);
END odp_varray_sample_proc_test;

**C# Code**

ISQLQuery query = eventhistorysession.CreateSQLQuery("BEGIN odp_varray_sample_proc_test(:param); END;");

query.SetParameter("param", new Int64[] { 259688 },new Int64ArrayType());

int final = query.ExecuteUpdate();

**Exception**

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was caught
  Message="could not execute native bulk manipulation query:BEGIN odp_varray_sample_proc_test(:param); END;[SQL: BEGIN odp_varray_sample_proc_test(:p0); END;]"
  Source="NHibernate"
  SqlString="BEGIN odp_varray_sample_proc_test(:p0); END;"
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.PerformExecuteUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ExecuteNativeUpdate(NativeSQLQuerySpecification nativeQuerySpecification, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.ExecuteUpdate()
       at TestDatabase.Program.InsertNhibernate() in C:\Jaroori Kachra\TestDatabase\TestDatabase\Program.cs:line 184
  InnerException: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException
       Message="ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ODP_VARRAY_SAMPLE_PROC_TEST'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"
       Source="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       DataSource="RACDV"
       Number=6550
       Procedure=""
       StackTrace:
            at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
            at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
            at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
            at NHibernate.Engine.Query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.PerformExecuteUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
       InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example type and procedure in Oracle:

```
TYPE NUMBER_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER NOT NULL INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE procedure_name(array IN NUMBER_ARRAY);
```

Example call of the stored procedure with NHibernate:

```
ISQLQuery query = _session.CreateSQLQuery("BEGIN procedure_name(:array); END;"
query.SetParameter("array", array, new Int64ArrayType());
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

You need to implement that Int64ArrayType yourself:

```
[Serializable]
public class Int64ArrayType : ImmutableType {
  public Int64ArrayType()
     : base(SqlTypeFactory.Int64) {
  }

  public override object Get(System.Data.IDataReader rs, string name) {
     return rs[name];
  }

  public override object Get(System.Data.IDataReader rs, int index) {
     return rs[index];
  }

  public override void Set(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index) {
     OracleCommand orclCmd = (OracleCommand)cmd;
     orclCmd.Parameters[index].OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
     orclCmd.Parameters[index].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
     orclCmd.Parameters[index].Value = value;
  }

  public override string ToString(object val) {
     return String.Join(";", (object[])val);
  }

  public override string Name {
     get { return "Int64ArrayType"; }
  }

  public override Type ReturnedClass {
     get { return typeof(long[]); }
  }

  public override object FromStringValue(string xml) {
     string[] stringElements = xml.Split(';');
     long[] array = new long[stringElements.Length];

     for (int i = 0; i < stringElements.Length; i++) {
        array[i] = Convert.ToInt64(stringElements[i]);
     }

     return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Cremor:Thanks for the reply can't I create a class and Map it to the type created.Say i'll create a mapping file which maps to type in Database. and pass the object of that type as a parameter to the procedure

Comment: Can u plz help me with Int64ArrayType implementation.I am facing issue in this

Comment: @anupam You don't need an additional class or mapping file. Just call the stored procedure like I showed and pass your array as parameter. I've edited my answer to contain the full Int64ArrayType.

Comment: @Cremor:I tried this but it is throwing me exception could not execute native bulk manipulation query.Following is my SP.      Create or replace
PROCEDURE odp_varray_sample_proc_test(param IN NUMBER_ARRAY)
IS
BEGIN 
insert into employee (emp_id, emp_name, emp_password, is_captain, no_of_mom) 
values (45455,'Adam','123545','Y',0);
END odp_varray_sample_proc_test;

Comment: @anupam Check the inner exception(s), there should be the real cause of the exception.

Comment: @Cremor:This is what inner exception gives **********Exception************************* InnerException: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException Message="ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE_NAME'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored" Source="Oracle Data Provider for .NET".

Comment: @anupam Show your code where you create and execute the SQLQuery.

Comment: @Cremor: Following are my code: using (ISession eventhistorysession = OpenSession()) { ITransaction tx = eventhistorysession.Transaction; tx.Begin(); ISQLQuery query = eventhistorysession.CreateSQLQuery("BEGIN procedure_name(:array1); END;"); query.SetParameter("array1", new Int64[] { 259688 }, new Int64ArrayType()); int final = query.ExecuteUpdate(); tx.Commit(); }

Comment: @anupam You are calling a stored procedure named "procedure_name" but you named your procedure "odp_varray_sample_proc_test". Or is this just a copy/paste error?

Comment: @Cremor:Yes it is just a copy paste Error.I am calling the SP named odp_varray_sample_proc_test.

Comment: @anupam I'm using Oracle 11.2, but I don't think that this makes a difference. Are you using the latest version of ODP.NET? If yes, I really don't have an idea any more. I've done it exactly like I showed and it works for me. **Edit:** You use the term "varray" in your procedure name. Are you sure you have created the type NUMBER_ARRAY like I showed it? Because a varray won't work.

Comment: @Cremor:I have updated my question with the Type created in database,Stored Procedure,C# Code and Exception coming.Though I am using Orcale 10 g ,but yes I have upgraded my Oracle ODP.net version to 11.2

Comment: @Cremor:When I am doing this like you shown                    Create or Replace TYPE NUMBER_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER NOT NULL INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;                                                         It is not allowing me to create and giving me following error.                                                               Error(2,22): PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context

Comment: @anupam I'm no Oracle expert, but I think you can only create such types inside of packages.

Comment: @Cremor:So when you have created this ,it was through package.

Comment: @anupam Yes, that's also why my type and procedure don't have a 'CREATE OR REPLACE' in front of them.

Comment: @Cremor:Does it mean that after creating package I need to call package from NHibernate rathar than calling procedure.Is it possible with Nhibernate to call Package.?

Comment: @anupam Sure, just call it like in PL/SQL: `BEGIN package_name.procedure_name(:array); END;`

Comment: @Cremor:Thanks a tons cremor.Now it is working fine just because of your help.With packages I have implemented it. One question I have is how to make it work with MS SQL Server.

Comment: @anupam Sorry, I've never used stored procedures in MS SQL Server, can't help you with that.

Comment: @Cremor:Can you tell me how to implement OracleDbType.Array with NHibernate

Comment: @anupam No idea, never needed that.

Comment: @Cremor:Any idea about how to pass List of custom objects?

Comment: @anupam No. PS: You should create new questions for those additional topics.

Comment: @Cremor:I have already created those questions .I didn't get any answers for them.

Answer (score 0):

Your type is a Nested Table. You need an Associative Array which is created by adding a `INDEX BY` clause like I already showed in my first answer.